# How can i import npm modules in es6 whiout webpack?

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, import

How can i import a npm module ( jquery for example ) whitout webpack??

```
import * as $ from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
```

it gives me $ is not defined

**QUESTION UPDATED**

this html:

```
<html>

<body>
  <p>hola</p>
  <script src="js/test.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this js:

```
import * as $ from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
console.log($());
```

gives me in console

> TypeError: $ is not a function

, but if i write in console after this mesage appear :

> console.log($());   it works as expected
>
> $() {} ​ : Object { jquery: "3.4.1", constructor: jQuery(),
>   length: 0, … }

Im not using any bundlers, using in browser

Comment: There's no way `$` should be `undefined` there. It might be an empty object, but it won't be `undefined`. `* as $` means "give me the module's namespace object and bind it to the identifier `$`". The MNO is created on first use, and all modules have one (if requested) regardless of their content.

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser, or Node.js? Are you using *any* kind of bundler? Does the script file get loaded?

Comment: (It's a *question*, not an *answer*. :-) )

Comment: upppss jejej you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the `jquery.js` file you're importing has `export` in it, you can't use `import` to import things from it. (You *can* use `import` to load it though it may not be a good idea, more below.) Native browser support only handles importing from things written as modules.

> ```
> import * as $ from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
> console.log($());
> ```
>
> gives me in console
>
> ```
> TypeError: $ is not a function
> ```

The reason for that is that when you use `* as $` in your `import`, you're importing the *module namespace object* for the module. The module namespace object is never callable, it's an object with properties for the exports of the module. You can use `* as x` syntax to import any script, even one that isn't written to be a module and so doesn't have `export` anywhere, but all you get is an empty object, because a script not written as a module doesn't have any exports.

> but if i write in console after this mesage appear :
>
> ```
> console.log($());
> ```
>
> it works as expected

That's because jQuery creates a global `$` using the `window` global. The only reason you couldn't use that global `$` in your module is that you've *shadowed* it by using `$` as the identifier for the module namespace object.

This would probably work:

```
import '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
```

...because that will load and run the jQuery script, which creates a global. Since that doesn't declare a module-local identifier with the name `$`, if you use `$` in your module, it uses the *global* `$` that jQuery creates.

But I'm leery of using `import` to load scripts that aren't designed to be used as modules. Instead, I think I'd just include jQuery using a `script` tag, and then have your module separately using the global `$`.

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js" type="module"></script>
```

(Or find a module-wrapped version of jQuery; I don't specifically know of one, but it probably exists.)

Comment: @tjcrowder thanks!. now i understand this kind of problems. many many thanks!

Comment: one more question: why `import * as $ from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';`works in webpack?? its because it uses babel or something like that??

Comment: @rodriciru - I have to admit I'm slightly surprised it does with `as` (I'd expect one of `import $ from "..."` or `import { $ } from "..."` to work, but not `import * as $ from "..."` -- with the latter I would have expected that you'd need to use `$.$()`, not just `$()`), but if it does it's because Webpack handles it for you.